# I deleted /usr/local/bin on my Mac. Is there any way I can see what was installed there?

Tags: terminal

I accidentally ran `rm -rf /usr/local/bin`.  Yes, I know, I'm an idiot.

Is there anything short of attempting to run every single application on my Mac to see what applications need to be reinstalled?

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't have a recent backup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most GUI Applications don't touch `/usr/local/bin`, so the Applications in your `/Applications` folder should still be in working condition. Some do install command line tools, but usually there is a menu item in the help or program menu to reinstall that command line item. Bottom line: If you don't use the command line much, you should be fine. If you use it frequently, you will see a "File not found" error when trying to run the command.

The only way to see what was in there, is indeed a backup.

Comment: I see, this is not a huge deal.  As I run command line programs, if I run into an error I will just install the appropriate program.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Homebrew, this directory tells you what you have lost:

> /usr/local/Cellar/

```
autoconf/     cloog/        hello/        libmagic/     libxml2/      p7zip/        ruby-build/   w3m/
autossh/      crystal-lang/ imagemagick/  libmpc/       libyaml/      pkg-config/   sdl/          x264/
awscli/       ffmpeg/       isl/          libpcl/       llvm/         pngcrush/     shiboken/     xvid/
bdw-gc/       freetype/     jpeg/         libpng/       mpfr/         pyside/       ssdeep/       xz/
binwalk/      gcc/          lame/         libtool/      openssl/      qt/           tree/         
brew-cask/    gmp/          libevent/     libvo-aacenc/ optipng/      rbenv/        unrar/
```

To correctly execute Homebrew reinstall scripts you might also need to restart bash session if you used rbenv.

Comment: You may just run `ls /usr/local/Cellar | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs brew reinstall`

Comment: @alexndreazevedo Use `brew link <name>` would be better and quick

Comment: @weaming, good suggestion! `ls /usr/local/Cellar | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs brew link`

Comment: you may need to run brew unlink before brew link or else it will say it's already linked (even though it's not)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to restore Homebrew installations:

`ls /usr/local/Cellar | awk -F"/" '{ print $1 }' | parallel 'brew unlink {}; brew link {}; '`

Comment: Where does `parallel` come from, don‘t think this is part of macOS? And if /usr/local/bin is lost, shouldn‘t brew itself get reinstalled first?